# In the formula $p\land q$, what do you call $p$ and $q$?

Tags: logic, terminology, definition

In the formula $p\to q$, we call $p$ the ***antecedent*** and $q$ the ***consequent***. Is there a similar naming for $p$ and $q$ in the formula $p\land q$?

I understand that $\land$ is commutative, so the naming convention would apply to the *syntax* of the formula.

Comment: They are called "conjuncts"

Comment: but if you wanted to follow the Latin gerundive part of speech seen in similar words such as addend, subtrahend, minuend, multiplicand, etc, then you would call them conjungends.

Comment: Only in the context of implication would you think "antecedent" means that.  If someone said "antecedent" you wouldn't think implication unless that was suggested elsewhere.  And consequent is not much better.  More direct terms are "implicant" and "implicand".  Although  those sound so similar that "condition" and "conclusion" are more commonly understood.  "Hypothesis" is also the correct term for "implicant" but most people today misuse that word.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$p \land q$ is called a conjunction. $p$ and $q$ individually are called **conjuncts**.

Similarly, $p \lor q$ is called a disjunction, with $p$ and $q$ individually being called *disjuncts*.

---

If you need to distinguish the conjuncts. *Left* and *right* work, as well as *first* and *second*.

Here's an example usage of *first conjunct*.

From Lloyd Humberstone's *The Connectives* on page 641.

> Unlike von Wright's treatment, this semantic treatment (we do not go into proof-theoretic matters) makes $\land^\bullet$ 'unbiased', whereas for von Wright, $A \land^\bullet B$ is biased specifically in favor of its first conjunct, which it implies.

Comment: Is there any naming convetion that distinguishes $p$ from $q$? Do you happen to know if terms such as _first conjuct_, referring to $p$ in $(p\land q)$, are ever used?

Comment: @Sam I've heard nothing but, given what happens with other binary functions/operators, some people might call $p$ _left_ or _leftmost_ rather than _first_ or _zeroth_. Fortunately, it's a symmetric operator, as is $\lor$.

Comment: I have a citation for the use of *first conjunct*. *... whereas for von Wright, $A \land^\bullet B$ is biased specifically in favor of the first conjunct, which it implies.* Page 641 *The Connectives* by Lloyd Humberstone.